# PyDev dependant project not found when running outside Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I suspect I am missing something obvious...

I have a project (projA say) in pyDev that is dependent on another (projB say). In my a module in projA I import a module from projB with the simple

```
import exampleModule
```

This works perfectly when running inside pyDev/Eclipse but if I run the script from the windows command prompt it cannot find the module and gives:

```
ImportError: No Module named exampleModule
```

Is there a means to tell python to look in the other projects source folder for the import from the command prompt? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your PYTHONPATH properly when running outside of PyDev (PyDev takes care of that when you set your source folders, which are the folders added to the PYTHONPATH).

Among the options to set your PYTHONPATH, you can do that in your shell by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable or you could change sys.path from inside the interpreter.